# Report on Cases and Activities

Tags: civireport

I need a dashlet for a user which lists scheduled activity details filtered on the 'case type' the activity sits in.   I can find these in search but cant seem to get a report to work - closest I can get is extended report  - Activity Pivot Chart (CiviCase)

Comment: I would expect you to be able to do this with the Case Detail Report? Have you tried that and if so, what exactly was the problem you had?

Comment: I think I've tried all the reports and templates The column options for listing activity details in Case Detail Report  are limited to Subject of the last activity in the case Activity type of the last activity Last Action Date Subject of the last completed activity in the case Activity type of the last completed activity Last Completed Action Date.  What my user would like on their dash is the ability to just list the scheduled activities of a set 'activity type'.

Comment: Still unclear to me, a list of scheduled activities of a set activity type you could just do with the Activity Detail report. So you must need more or you have to adapt to my speed of understanding :-)

Comment: If you are on Drupal, a workaround could be to build what you want via a view. there are then solutions for how to have this listed as a dashlet. we tend to find we want 'full width' and hence just add them as blocks in eg the Highlight region so they should on dashboard above the dashlets

Answer (score 0):

If I can perform a straight forward query in search with regard to finding an “activity type’ within a specified ‘case type’  would it not be a significant progression for the CRM to be able to perform this as a report.

As an implementor I finally got around the problem using smart groups, but ..  seeing as the table join is already part of the ‘extended report’ functionality would it not be a massive progression for Civi report to offer this in a more direct way.

Many thanks to the suggestions to make a view and incorporate as a block, I can do this, I appreciate the power of the views module, should it be necessary.  The push to make civiCRM a software capable of case management  and it being really useful to organisations who wish to manage actual case requirements means that a fairly simple code change could offer significant Implementor level advancement.

I really don’t want to try and remember how to code, yours in eternal laziness x

Answer (score 0):

These days you have more options. You can install the dataprocessor extension (see https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/dataprocessor), which gives you the option to create custom searches by only using the interface. It is a bit like drupal views, but it works inside CiviCRM. And you can publish the search as a dashlet.